# How to create a MFC CSliderCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a new MFC project with MS VS 2010 using their wizard (I chose single document if it matters). Then, I created a dialog box and from the toolbox I dragged a new slider. Using VS's wizard (right click on dialog-->add class) I created a class for my dialog called `MyDialog`. Next, I used VS's wizard to add a variable to to slider.

So now, in my `MyDialog` class I have a `CSliderCtrl` and I can't get it to work.
I tried to use `SetRange()` and\or `SetPos()` in `OnInitDialog()` but they crash to program and throws an exception.

If I create a new `CSliderCtrl` in `OnInitDialog()` and set it's range with `SetRange()` like so, it does works.

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CSliderCtrl *TrackBar = new CSliderCtrl;

    TrackBar->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,CRect(20, 20, 60, 280),this, IDC_SLIDER1);
    int min,max;
    TrackBar->GetRange(min,max);
    TrackBar->SetPos(10);
    return TRUE;
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    m_mySlider.SetRange(1,100); //sending true\false doesn't matter
    return TRUE;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The program doesn't crash and it doesn't throw an exception. You get a dialog with a failed assertion. It tells you what pre-condition failed. To solve your issued, read the documentation. The documentation for [`OnInitDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59.aspx) states to *first call the base class OnInitDialog*. This is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the technical error , I indeed get a failed assertion. Also thanks for the solution! I missed the part that states I must call the base class' onInitDialog. Kudos :) –

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shown, you missed this important line,

```
       CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
```

You should add SetRange and SetPos calls after the above line.